# KEIL MCB1700 Evaluation Board Bricked

Tags: arm, keil, nxp-microcontroller

I have a KEIL MCB1700 evaluation board (NXP LCP1768 uC), that I program with an NXP LCP-Link2 and Keil uVision5.

Things have been running smoothly until I've done some PLL0 configuration tests, willing to speed up the CPU clock. Now I can't program the board anymore : when trying to do so, I get the following message :

"Cannot Reset Target, shutting Down debug session"
"Error, floash download failed - target DLL has been cancelled"

And the build output is :

Load "E:\ARM Examples\Boards\Keil\MCB1700\Demo\Flash\Demo.axf" 
Cannot access Memory (@ 0x400fc040, Write, Acc Size: 4 Byte)
Cannot access Memory
Error: Flash Download failed  -  Target DLL has been cancelled
Flash Load finished at 17:12:18

(I've tried to load a demo program to make sure the code isn't the issue)

I've also tried to program another board with the same LPC-Link2 and computer, it worked fine.

Is there a way to force a "factory" restoration of the registers/board ?

Thanx in advance.

Best regards.

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the MCU in ISP mode and then program it as usual.

To run the MCB1700 in ISP mode, you should close jumper INT0, press INT0 button and while pressing it, program the board as usual.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer ! I'll give that a try and let you know how things go.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the exact same message when I try to program it with the INT0 button pushed.

Do you think it coud help to erase the flash memory using the "Flash Magic" tool ?

Comment: You can also try to press and release reset button while pressing INT0 and then program.

Comment: Erasing the entire flash using Flash Magic should help. There is just a question, if it is possible - it may have similar simptoms as programming using jtag

Comment: Solved it with the INT0 + RESET method, thank you so much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Just got an answer from Keil support, works perfect :

"Hello Eric,
if really the last flashed program is causing the trouble, then you can try pressing and holding the INT0 button while pressing RESET button. INT0 asserted should force the chip into bootloader mode and so does not execute the faulty program.
Maybe you also need to disable any reset options in the debug reset and connect configuration:

http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/ulink2/ulink2_ctx_debug.htm

Then try to connect. Hope, this helps."

Thanx you for helping me though !

Best regards